# Is it possible to edit textarea and save HTML file with changes locally in browser?

Tags: html

I have this crazy idea to have a simple file `.html` with textareas which can be edited but I don't want to have a database or any backend, just this one file and to be able to open it in browser and in browser add text and save it somehow....is this possible without backend and Database?

This a simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
    At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.
</textarea>


</body>
</html>
```

And what I want is to be able to save the changes made in Textarea to be permanent so when I copy that .htm file those changes should be there in source code of that htm file.

Comment: Where would it be saved? Would other visitors see that change?

Comment: You can use browser's localstorage.

Comment: i dont know what you mean man but if it helps add contenteditable="true" attr to elements you want to be editable

Comment: No visitors, this is just for me locally on my PC. It should be saved into itself

Comment: Actually, It is a good idea to have a browser with IDE features :D

Comment: But why not just use a text/code editor? Anyway, the thought is interesting, but the question could use some improvements in wording.

Comment: Also, have you simply tried `CTRL+S` in your browser? It seems to work in Chrome, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if this is possible simply by using a browsers `Save page as...` (or similarly named) feature, which can usually be easily accessed via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

Try this:

- Create a very simple `.html` file that has some element with the `contenteditable` attribute.
- Open that file in your browser.
- Change the contents of the editable element from within the browsers.
- Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and save the file **over itself**.
- Reload the page or reopen the same file.

The changes you performed from within the browser should be there and should also be reflected in other editors or browsers.

However, as this is a browser feature that is not covered by any standard, some browsers might not offer this feature or save the file in its original, unchanged state. Also, the way browsers handle this can obviously be subject to change.

At the time of writing, this has been *successfully* tested with these browsers / OS:

- Chrome 60, Windows
- Opera 47, Windows
- Firefox 55, Windows and OSX

Browsers / OS that do *not* save the changes:

- Edge 40, Windows (also, opening local files is non-trivial)
- Chrome 60, OSX
- Safari Version 10.1.2 (12603.3.8)
- Opera 47, OSX

Comment: It took me a while to realize this as well... funny, how our brains work sometimes. :)

Comment: Damn it doesn't work...I just tested it now.... :( It saves the HTML file but not the changes I have made

Comment: What browser did you test this with? I tried it on Opera and Chrome in Windows and that seems to work just fine.

Comment: In Chrome... I deleted the text from Textarea and wrote something else and saved the file but in saved file the source code is the same as in the original file. No changes. Now i lost hope that this is going to work as i wanted it....I think this can't be done.

Comment: But in Firefox it works!!! Heh...man this is crazy. I'm on a iMAC BTW, maybe it's because of a different OS.

Comment: Yeah, after all, these are browser features that are not part of any (web) standard whatsoever. This also means these features are subject to change. Maybe there is a browser out there that offers a `Save page` feature in addition to `Save page as...`, or maybe some browsers will add this at some point. Always hard to tell. Maybe we can get a small *compatibility list* of some sorts up. What versions of Chrome and Firefox are you using?

Comment: @domsson  is there a way to skip the "save as" popup (just save when press ctrl+S)?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to edit an HTML file on the fly using the `contenteditable` attribute, or simply from your browser's web inspector.

For saving the page you could use `localStorage` or other mechanisms to save it just on your computer.

It's even possible to create a simple text editor that works in your browser, just by going to this URL: `data:text/html,<html contenteditable></html>`

You can have a look at this blog post for more: https://www.simonewebdesign.it/how-to-make-browser-editor-with-html5-contenteditable/ (I am the author)

Comment: That is very interesting! and what's *really* interesting (in regards to OP's question) is that, as least in Chrome, you can just hit `ctrl+s` and save the _edited_ contents to a file that, when loaded into the browser again, will show the performed edits.

Answer (score 0):

In **HTML5** you can use **local storage** to save the data.

> The localStorage object stores the data with no expiration date. The
>   data will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be
>   available the next day, week, or year.

use the following example in javascript to store and retrieve the data:

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

Comment: No it's not the way I thought it...I want it to be permanent...so when i open that .html file that edited text should be there...I am not sure if that is possible...So actually it should work like you are editing that .html file source code

Comment: as per the w3school documentation .. The localStorage object stores the data with no expiration date. The data will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be available the next day, week, or year.PLease check the following link : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Nirzar, OP basically wants to save the changes performed in the `.html` file to that very same file, so that opening it with another browser or plain text editor would show these changes.

Comment: @domsson ohh thanx for clarifying